# Ubuntu 16.04 automatically logs out after admin change

Tags: 16.04, login, administrator

I'm experiencing an issue where Ubuntu logs the user out immediately after logging in - there's a few moments of black screen following login and I'm returned back to the logon prompt, this is occurring for all users including Guest.

For background: I recently changed my standard user account to an admin account  (there are now two admin accounts and one guest). From what I've found online it sounds as though doing this might have caused some sort of permission or ownership clash on a system file, but I'm not certain this is the case.

I've already looked online and found and attempted the following solutions without success:

1. Remove .Xauthority file and restart lightdm service
   ([Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will automatically log out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772777/ubuntu-16-04-lts-will-automatically-log-out))
2. Reinstalling Unity
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 
   sudo apt-get install unity 
   ([I am logged out immediately after logging in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367260/i-am-logged-out-immediately-after-logging-in/435296))
3. Reestablishing owner and group of my home directory.
   sudo chown -R username:username /home/useusername
   (as above)

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I'd like to improve my Linux knowledge as well as learn how to solve this particular issue. Any resources or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you change this account to admin?

Comment: Within the Ubuntu settings menu under Accounts. I needed to do this from the existing admin account.