# Ubuntu 18.04 automatically logs out when I close the laptop lid

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, power-management

I have 18.04 on my lenovo legion. Usually, when I go to bed I close the lid and the computer goes into suspend/sleep and when I wake up, I unlock it and pick up where I left. But very recently- last week or 2, when I close the lid and wake up in the morning, I find that ubuntu has logged me out. and of course, when I log back in, all windows and apps are closed, sometimes I lose my progress on unsaved projects and the sites I wanted to have open.

does anyone else face this issue? my guess is that I have nvidia 430.50 driver and I installed it along with tensorflow. But recently the system shows this partial update warning and the only packages there are the nvidia driver 440.59 version. I don't want to break my tensorflow installation and also potentially break the os by installing it. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Settings for sleep locking]

Disable the locking screen when waking-up in your lock screen settings.

Comment: I don't see the lock screen setting. There's an automatic screen lock in privacy and that's turned off already.

Comment: Type in "lock" into your settings search and you should find "Screen Locking" and it will be there with the option.

Comment: that's how I found the lock setting and it's the one inside 'privacy' -> screen lock = off. the other result is a keyboard shortcut. I've also looked inside the gnoe -tweaks and there's no result. I really don't see what you have in your screen shot. is it 18.04?

Comment: Also, I don't see what it has to do with my question. my question is about logging out and not locking screen.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Refer to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/772777/ubuntu-16-04-lts-will-automatically-log-out